# Openssl command if failing with alert handshake error

Tags: openssl, handshake, sslv3

I am trying to run an openssl s_client command but it returns me a handshake failure response. Here is the command with output

```
OpenSSL> s_client -connect host:port -showcerts

CONNECTED(00000003) 89154:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:
```

Can some one help what is happening here?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

You are using openssl version 0.9.8 is pretty old and TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 and SNI are not supported. And probably the target server is rejecting SSLv2/SSLv3/TLSv1.

Try openssl version 1.0 or above and see if able to show cert. details.

```
OpenSSL> s_client -connect host:port -servername vhostname -showcerts
```